# In lines starting with specific word followed by words separated by semicolon, replace semicolon with a comma and wrap the words in double quotes

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm trying to change certain lines in my file using notepad++ and I have very less knowledge at regular expressions and henceforth seeking help. 
Any kind of help is appreciable.

Find all the lines that looks like as  **`See ABC'D EFG;IJKL;FOO;BAR;XXXXson on.`**

1. Lines that starts with word **`"See"`**
2. After that,there are words all in Capital letters and separated by semicolon
3. Words can have special characters

   a)  space

   b) **`'`** (apostrophy)

   c) **`,`** (comma)

   d) **`-`** (hiphen)
4. Ends with a full stop **`.`**

And replace those lines as:

```
See:["ABC'D EFG","IJKL","FOO","BAR",....]
```

Comment: Your English isn't bad, but it may be unclear.  Do you want to quote each term separated by semicolon?  What would happen if the line had more than one semicolon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the number of semi-colon is variable. You need to proceed in two passes.
Use `Replace All` for the two passes:

find: `^See \K([A-Z ,;'-]+)\.`
replace: `["$1"]`

and then:

find: `(?:\G(?!^)|^See \["(?=[^"]*"]))[^";]*\K;`
replace: `", "`

The first pass is easy to understand, it only finds corresponding lines, remove the final dot and encloses the part with uppercase letters, commas, spaces, semi-colons, apostrophes and hyphens between double quotes and square brackets.

The second pass needs to replace only semi-colons inside quotes and square brackets for lines that start with `See`. To do that I used the second branch `^See \["(?=[^"]*"])` to reach the interesting lines and the `\G` anchor in the second branch to ensure that the next matches are contiguous to the first. Since `[^";]*` excludes the double quote, once the last semicolon is reached, the first branch can no longer succeed and the contiguity is broken.

Comment: @user3471526: I don't understand your comment, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

find what: `See ([A-Z'\-, ]+)\;([A-Z'\-, ]+)\.`
replace with: `See:["\1", "\2"]`
see https://regex101.com/r/bfJkN6/3
also tested on my notepad++, got See:["ABC'D EFG", "IJKL"]
I updated the regex to catch multi hits on https://regex101.com/r/bfJkN6/5
`See ((([A-Z'\-, ]+)\;)+)([A-Z'\-, ]+)\.`

Comment: Thank you very much and it really worked for me too.

I am extremely sorry for I did not mention that there could be "n" number of semicolons as well. So, I think it is limited only to one semicolon case.

Comment: i edited my response to catch multi hits with the same regex. unfortunately, I'm not familiar with notepad++ enough to tell you how to post-process it. the regex will give you 3 vars - one with n-1 matches, one with the last match and one with the match before the last (which you don't need). scripting languages will require at least a line to do this processing, so I doubt the notepad will give you better results...

Answer (score 0):

Use **`\W`** which matches any non-word character

***Example https://regex101.com/r/lFANF0/4***

*Find* ***`See\s([A-Z' ]+)\W(\w+)\.`***  and *Replace* ***`See:["$1","$2"]`***

> [image]
>
> *1stGroup **`(\w+\'\w+\s+)`** **`\w+`** matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
>
> **`+`** Matches between one and unlimited times
>
> **`\s+`** matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
>
> 2nd Group **`(\w+\W*\w+)`** **`\W*`** matches any non-word character (equal to [`^a-zA-Z0-9_]`)*

Comment: check the question again, there are some parameters in the search string you missed...